# Is there some trick to resizing encrypted VirtualBox `.vdi`s?

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

For resizing normal `.vdi` drives in VirtualBox, my procedure was:

1. Cleanup snapshots and shutdown the Guest
2. `VBoxManage modifyhd  --resize
3. Boot VM with live CD and resize the partition inside

That used to work. For some reason it doesn't for encrypted `.vdi` (or something else changed). Is there a trick to it, I'm not aware of?

VBox's disk Encryption:

[image: vbox settings showing encryption]

VBox is aware of the new size:

[image: vbox showing new size]

GParted inside the guest is not aware of the new size:

[image: gparted is not aware]

Someone on stackoverflow said, he...

`...figured out that I needed to delete all Snapshots. But this wouldnt [sic] work for some reasons. So I made a clone with not Snapshots and then I could use Gparted in a proper way.`

However that didn't seem to work for me. I'm not linking to the answer because he got a bunch of "firednly" downvotes for it being off-topic.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details then "that didn't seem to work for me", at this point, you are limiting the number of people who can answer your question to a very small group of people who encountered this problem.  I suggest editing your question to clarify it.  It would also be nice if you removed the meta statements about the non-linked question[.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305635/virtualbox-vm-no-unallocated-space-shown-in-gparted)

Answer (score 0):

The closest way I've been able to "resize a encrypted VDI" is to

1. Unencrypt vdi
2. Perform normal resizing operations e.g defrag, zero free space, `VBoxManage modifyhd --resize`
3. Encrypt vdi